# Use iptables to block all incoming IPs

Tags: iptables, ip

Is it possible block all incoming IP addresses, allowing only one or two IP addresses access on Ubuntu server?

Answer (score 3):

**Blocking all IPs except 1 or 2:**

```
sudo /sbin/iptables -I INPUT -s xxx.xxx.x.xxx -j ACCEPT
sudo /sbin/iptables -I INPUT -s xxx.xxx.x.yyy -j ACCEPT
sudo /sbin/iptables -I INPUT -j DROP
```

The first command blocks all IP's; the second and third tell the computer to accept connections from specific IP's.

If you want to make these changes permanent, after running the commands above, run the following.

**Install iptables-persistent**

```
sudo apt-get install iptables-persistent
```

**Save your iptables changes to a file**

```
iptables-save > /etc/iptables/rules.v4
```

... And that should work!

---

See @ThomasWard's answer; it's more complete, and if you're using your server for anything web related (including updates), my answer will create major issues.

Comment: Keep in mind, these will flush on reboot.

Comment: True.  But you just need to add the rules to your `/etc/iptables/rules.v4` file, provided you have `iptables-persistent` installed.

Comment: And since we are talking about servers, be careful to not lock yourself out by forgetting to add your own IP.

Comment: Yes, lol, that would not be funny.

Comment: This won't work because it's first-match first-handle in the ruleset.  So in this case, you need your ACCEPT rules above DROP.  But you're also missing a lot of other crucial bits, see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the other answer here doesn't take into account three cases which are relevant:

1. Local traffic to the system itself.  (`localhost`, etc. via the `lo` adapter)
2. Traffic *related* to other traffic you've made (responses to outgoing connections, etc.)
3. ICMP responses from your own network (which are sometimes necessary depending on the network environment).

Most residential networks or average networks have no need for #3, but #1 and #2 are critical - #1 so traffic to the system from the system works (think localhost connections for local services or `sudo` for its own internal hostname lookup), and #2 because you need to be able to receive traffic related to established connections you've made outbound to get DNS responses, HTTP/HTTPS packet data for your package installations or updates, etc.

So, the solution I would pose is you do this:

**If you have any `iptables` rules already, flush them out with `sudo iptables -F` so we start with a 'clean slate' before doing this.**

```
# This first command is OK, setting INPUT to default ACCEPT becase
# we will force all unpermitted traffic to DROP at the end of this ruleset.
sudo iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A INPUT -i lo -m comment --comment "Accept localhost, computer to itself" -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -m comment --comment "Accept traffic related to established connections and this system's outgoing traffic" -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A INPUT -s a.b.c.d --comment "Accept inbound connections from a.b.c.d" -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A INPUT -s w.x.y.z --comment "Accept inbound connections from w.x.y.z" -j ACCEPT
# Repeat previous line as many times as you need to in order to accept traffic
# that you want to accept, but also add a line for the IP address you are 
# currently connected to the system from if a remote SSH session, otherwise
# you may lock yourself out.
sudo iptables -A INPUT -m comment --comment "Drop all other traffic inbound" -j DROP
```

This will do what anonymous2 was attempting to do but also permit your computer to still work with the Internet and letting your system function properly.  This also lets your system continue to operate until you add the DROP rule at the very end (don't add that rule until you've also whitelisted the IP address YOU are accessing from, which SHOULD be one of the ALLOW rules above, and you can add as MANY

Make sure to install `iptables-persistent` and store these rules in `/etc/iptables/rules.v4` or else these rules won't persist.